# Using a Client Certificate from the withCredentials bindings in Jenkins

Tags: ssl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

There is an option in Jenkins to add a global credential 'Kind' called : "X.509 Client Certificate" and I would like to use this within my build securely, to invoke a RESTful API using cURL.

[image]

I add the Client Key, Client Certificate, Server CA Chain to the appropriate boxes, add an ID, a Description and head to my Jenkins pipeline.

Now I consult the documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) to look for how to use the 'withCredentials' bindings to actually use my key and certificate securely. I don't see any reference to the bindings for using the X.509 Client Certificate? I see 'Certificate' but that's a different option and doesn't expose a private key for example.

Can somebody please help me understand when in the pipeline code, what do I use inside the withCredentials block to specify the appropriate type, and pass variable names for the client cert, client key, and server chain.

```
withCredentials([WhatHere?(credentialsId: 'myClientCert', variable?: 'key',variable2?: 'cert')]) {
    
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **X.509 Client Certificate** option which is part of the docker plugin, has recently changed its name as it used to be named **Docker Certificate Directory** (the behavior itself has not changed), therefore is it is tricky to find it in the `withCredentials` [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).
The option you are looking for is called `dockerCert` (named after the old option) and it includes two parameter inputs `variable` and `credentialsId`:

> *dockerCert*
> **variable**
> Name of an environment variable to be set during the build.
> Its value will be the absolute path of the directory where the {ca,cert,key}.pem files will be created.
> You probably want to call this variable DOCKER_CERT_PATH, which will be understood by the docker client binary.
> *Type: String*
> **credentialsId**
> Credentials of an appropriate type to be set to the variable.
> *Type: String*

Pipeline usage example:

```groovy
withCredentials([dockerCert(credentialsId: 'myClientCert', variable: 'DOCKER_CERT_PATH')]) {
    // code that uses the certificate files
}
```

Comment: Hi @noam so - can i assume despite being called 'dockerCert' it can be used for anything, and it simply exposes the path , and inside that folder will be 3 files, 'ca.pem' , 'cert.pem' and 'key.pem'?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy what do you mean by anything? you can use it for all credentials defined as **X.509 Client Certificate**. For them the 3 certificate files will be copied to the path specified in the `variable` parameter.

Comment: Sorry what i meant by 'anything' is that these certificates can be used in any way - not just by docker - and I can answer my own question, with 'yes they can be used for any purpose'.

Comment: This is working wonderfully thank you @noam helmer. 

Do you know if there is any work in the pipeline to have Jenkins refactor this support with better documentation and remove references to Docker? Would be great to add it onto the backlog if not? Perhaps I could even do the refactoring?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy I didn't see any request of this type, you can open one in the plugin's [request page](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67324?jql=resolution%20is%20EMPTY%20and%20component%3D18724)

Comment: @RenegadeAndy @Noam Helmer What entity sets `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` value? I expected jenkins docker plugin to copy client certs which are set in jenkins creds identified by `credentialsId ` as jenkins docs state. It's not clear at all who or what should set `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` to `/etc/docker/certs.d/[registry_url]` as docker docs require. `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` is custom value similar to credentials and following the logic of other credentials types like `usernamePassword`,`/etc/docker/certs.d/[registry_url]` path has to be stored in credentials

Answer (score 0):

On my Jenkins, it's

```
withCredentials([certificate(aliasVariable: 'ALIAS_VAR', 
    credentialsId: 'myClientCert', 
    keystoreVariable: 'KEYSTORE_VAR', 
    passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD_VAR')]) { 
... 
}
```

Hint: If you add `/pipeline-syntax/` to your Jenkins URL, it will take you to a snippet generator that will generate some snippets for you based on your input. That's what I used to generate the above snippet.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the code for when you use 'Certificate' as the kind - which is different to using a X.509 Client Certificate.

Comment: You can select the exact type you want in the snippet generator.

Comment: Yes - if you do this please note that the type is called 'Docker Client Certificate' inside the UI.

I hope perhaps Jenkins will tidy this up , as it has nothing to do with Docker, this can be applied to any HTTP Client Certificate Use case.